# Merge the "multi-site" and "multisite" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Actually there are 84 questions tagged [multisite](/questions/tagged/multisite), and 30 questions tagged [multi-site](/questions/tagged/multi-site). Those tags should be merged, and probably [multisite](/questions/tagged/multisite) should be kept (making the other a synonym).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. [multisite](/questions/tagged/multisite) -> [multi-site](/questions/tagged/multi-site).